# How to send as a proxy address

Tags: email-server, microsoft-office-365, office365

I have sort of a weird situation that I need to get solved.

We use office 365 (exchange online) for our email server.

My company is going through a rebranding. Currently, we have one domain that we have, @companyname.com, they are trying to add a new domain, @newcomanyname.com. What I am hoping to do is add a proxy address for all the users in @companyname.com domain for the @newcompanydomain.com.

For example, user@companyname.com would be able to receive email at both user@companyname.com and user@newcompanyname.com. I know that the proxy address can be done, the main question that I have is, can we have the users send from the proxy address @newcompany.com. If we can how can we do it?

If you have any questions or need more information, please let me know and I wil provide what I can.

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using groups.
Though it is not the prettiest solution, because it does not work very well with many users and might require manual labor.

- Create a group. Name it as e-mail address you would like to send from
- Add user to the newly created group
- Move proxy address from user to the group and make it primary
- Add permission to SELF for uset to be able to send from the group

Now user can pick the group in From field in Outlook.
Wotks OK for common email aliases and small number of users. I guess you can even automate group creation using Microsoft Flow but I never tried it myself